# How to make SVG fit in pseudo element

Tags: html, css

```css
div::after {
  content: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Inkscape-small.svg');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(124, 124, 124);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

How do I make the SVG fit in the pseudo element and also center it? I cannot apply styles to the content inside the pseudo element.

Comment: If you comment the `width` and `height` property, it the svg will go into the middle of the `div`.

Comment: But what if I need it to have a width and height?

Comment: You can just remove the `::after`, and it works.

Comment: Do you want input `svg image` into a `grey space`?

Comment: @rensothearin Yeah but it's supposed to be a pseudo element.

Comment: @Adhitya Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include `svg image` in `gray space`, maybe the code can use it like this.
You can write `div{...}` first and then write `pseudo element`

**So will got output like this snippet**

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(124, 124, 124);
  display: relative;
  }
div::after {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Inkscape-small.svg');
  content:'';
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to do you can try this

```css
div::after {
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"%3F%3E%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="390" height="390"%3E%3Cpath d="M163.15,27.83L28.81,165.3C-16.58,221.51 59.7,214.97 92.4,231.16C104.13,243.15 47.44,252 59.17,264C70.9,275.99 130.1,287.1 141.85,299.09C153.58,311.08 117.84,323.8 129.57,335.79C141.3,347.78 168.43,336.42 173.51,364.1C177.13,383.88 222.4,372.6 244.54,356.4C256.27,344.4 222.1,345.53 233.83,333.54C263,303.71 290.16,322.7 300.14,292.81C305.07,278.04 257.2,270.04 268.95,258.05C302.7,238.34 419.35,225.51 364,170.16L224.75,27.83C207.72,11.48 179.3,11.3 163.15,27.83 zM317.46,292.81C317.46,299.63 367.71,304.1 367.71,291.2C360.55,270.48 323.4,271.88 317.46,292.81 zM91.1,329.05C103,339.34 121.38,326.49 126.89,312.13C115.36,296.81 72.2,312.68 91.1,329.05 zM311.16,306.82C295.82,320.58 312.88,334.54 328,325.65C331.37,322.23 327.91,310.24 311.16,306.82z"/%3E%3Cpath fill="%23fff" d="M131,238.6C134.59,240.83 188.89,251.86 202.16,254.06C206.76,255.03 203.5,259.77 197.16,262.97C182.86,266.77 113.5,238.6 131,238.6z"/%3E%3Cpath fill="%23fff" d="M216.63,37.47L269.78,91.45C274.82,96.6 274.75,106.58 271.93,109.45L245.54,88.34L240.35,119.6L218.3,107.96L182.99,130.27L171.3,83.24L152.33,116.06L123.33,116.06C111.51,116.06 110.12,101.06 120.86,90.32C139.62,70.07 161.15,49.43 172.85,37.47C184.61,25.45 205.1,25.79 216.63,37.47z"/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A');
        background-size: 50px 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgb(124, 124, 124);
        content:"";
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I've used this tool to [encode the SVG content to be used with CSS](https://devtools360.com/en/svg/encode), but I guess you still can use the URL